# "Hacking" many to many relationships in Power BI?

Tags: many-to-many, powerbi

I need a bit of help working out a conundrum here.  I have a big table of sales data, also have a table of purchase data for the same products.  I would like to be able to have a matrix of the purchase data be sliced by a matrix of the sales data (or having a slicer filter data from both tables) - specifically to show purchasing trends by period for a specific item while also viewing sales trends by period.  I am sure that there is some way to hack this with a DAX measure or maybe a table that connects to   but can't quickly come up with it and need to focus my attention on another task.  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try searching for "many to many" and "bridge table". Your question isn't specific enough to write a concise answer.

Comment: many-to-many relations have nothing to do with your problem. You need to build a star schema with 2 fact tables ('Sales' and 'Purchases'), and at least 2 shared dimensions: 'Product' and 'Date'. After that, you can write DAX, and it should be straightforward.

Comment: Provide a sample copy of data for the sales and purchase table. I might be able to help, solved a very similar problem last week.

Comment: All, thanks for replies.  I got diverted on another project, will refocus on this one in next 2 days (I think "galaxy schema" is what I need here as opposed to star schema however)..  @AlexisOlson I have not forgotten about our heatmap convo from a few weeks ago, intending to pick that back up sometime this week too... :)